# Where is Comparable <=> implemented?

Tags: ruby, ruby-module, ruby-comparable

I'm reading [Comparable module](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Comparable.html).

And trying to see where `Comparable` module **itself** is implemented, but I can’t find it anywhere.
I only see places where it gets added using `include`.

Isn't that the module should have its implementation provided elsewhere? So that you just do a plug and play by using `include`?

Or is that in the following code:

```
class Geeksforgeeks
      
# include comparable module
include Comparable
attr :name
      
    def <=>(other_name) # LineA
        name.length <=> other_name.name.length # LineB
    end
      
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end
```

LineA: is something at the `Geeksforgeeks` class level.

LineB: is something at Integer (Length) level.

If that's the case then where is `<=>` written for Integers?

**EDIT:**

My code builds without `include Comparable`. I'm just not so sure what it means though:

```
class Geeksforgeeks
    
# does not include Comparable
attr :name
        
    def <=>(other_name) # LineA
        name.length <=> other_name.name.length # LineB
    end
        
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end

jack = Geeksforgeeks.new('jack')
pete = Geeksforgeeks.new('pete')
alexander = Geeksforgeeks.new('Alexander')

def areSameGeeks(g1, g2)
    if g1 <=> g2
        puts 'equal'
    else 
        puts 'not equal'
    end
end

areSameGeeks(jack,pete) # equal
areSameGeeks(jack, jack) # equal
areSameGeeks(jack, alexander) # equal
```

Like why are all three, returning 'equal'?

Comment: Here you go: [`Integer#<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Integer.html#3C-3D-3E-method)

Comment: @Stefan Nice. so including `Comparable` will get you all implementations of it for primitive Ruby types?

Comment: No, if you include `Comparable`, you have to implement `<=>` and return `-1`, `0`, or `1`. The above example does this by calling `<=>` on `name.length`. It merely reuses the existing implementation for integers.

Comment: How's that different from what I said? The code in my question ends up using the implementation for integers. And Integer is a primitive...Nonetheless it has to write its own (for `Geeksforgeeks`), because comparison for `Geeksforgeeks` variables are different comparisons of `Int`s

Comment: I meant that `Integer#<=>` is provided by `Integer`, not `Comparable`. You don’t have to `include Comparable` in order to call `Integer#<=>`.

Comment: @Stefan Great point. Now I'm confused. My code runs without errors if I remove the `include Comparable` line. However it doesn't do a correct comparison for `Geeksforgeeks.new('jack') == Geeksforgeeks.new('pete')`. Why do you need `include Comparable` to make it work? Aren't you just defining a `<=>` method? I suppose it's because then you're defining a single method of `<=>` i.e. not a way to handle 3 methods of `==`, `<`, `>`. Is that right?

Comment: "Now I'm confused. My code runs without errors if I remove the `include Comparable` line" – Your code doesn't actually do anything, it just defines a class. It doesn't instantiate that class, it doesn't call any methods, it does pretty much nothing. Therefore, it is more or less irrelevant what you delete or add or change: since the code is never executed, it will never fail.

Comment: @JörgWMittag can you see the edit?

Comment: `if g1 <=> g2` makes no sense. `g1 <=> g2` returns 0, 1 or -1, all of which are true in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example might help to understand how `Comparable` works:

```
module MyComparable
  def ==(other)
    (self <=> other) == 0
  end

  def <(other)
    (self <=> other) < 0
  end

  def >(other)
    (self <=> other) > 0
  end
end
```

The above module defines the methods `==`, `<` and `>`. Their implementations rely on another method `<=>` which isn't defined by the module.

To actually use the module's methods, the including class has to provide this `<=>` in a meaningful way, e.g.:

```
class Foo
  include MyComparable   # <- this adds its instance methods to Foo

  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def <=>(other)
    name.length <=> other.name.length
  end
end
```

This gives us:

```
Foo.new("abc") == Foo.new("123")  #=> true
Foo.new("abc") == Foo.new("1234") #=> false
Foo.new("abc") <  Foo.new("1234") #=> true
```

`==` and `<` are from `MyComparable`, but it only works because of `Foo#<=>`.

A similar approach is taken by [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Enumerable.html) which requires an `each` method to be implemented by the including class.

Answer (score 2):

> And trying to see where `Comparable` module **itself** is implemented, but I can’t find it anywhere.

`Comparable` is part of the core library of whatever Ruby implementation you are using. For example:

- in [Rubinius](https://rubinius.com/), `Comparable` is implemented in [`core/comparable.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/comparable.rb),
- in [TruffleRuby](https://graalvm.org/ruby/), it is implemented in [`src/main/ruby/truffleruby/core/comparable.rb`](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/blob/master/src/main/ruby/truffleruby/core/comparable.rb),
- in [MRuby](https://mruby.org/), it is implemented in [`mrblib/compar.rb`](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/mrblib/compar.rb),
- in [Opal](https://opalrb.com/), it is implemented in [`opal/corelib/comparable.rb`](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/comparable.rb),
- in [JRuby](https://www.jruby.org/), it is implemented in [`core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyComparable.java`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyComparable.java),
- in [IronRuby](https://ironruby.net/), it is implemented in [`Src/Libraries/Builtins/Comparable.cs`](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironruby/blob/master/Src/Libraries/Builtins/Comparable.cs), and
- in [YARV](https://atdot.net/yarv/), it is implemented in [`compar.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/compar.c).

However, I personally find it not so much interesting where something is *implemented* but rather where it is *specified*. `Comparable` is specified in section 15.3.3 *`Comparable`* of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html). A less formal specification is given in [`core/comparable/`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/tree/master/core/comparable) of [The Ruby Spec Suite aka `ruby/spec`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/).

It is also described in [*The Ruby Programming Language* by David Flanagan and Yukihiro 'matz' Matsumoto](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177), [*Programming Ruby* by Dave Thomas, Andy Hunt, and Chad Fowler](https://pragprog.com/titles/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0-4th-edition/), and of course in the [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Comparable.html)

> If that's the case then where is `<=>` written for Integers?

`Integer#<=>` is part of the core library of whatever Ruby implementation you are using. For example:

- in Rubinius, `Integer#<=>` is implemented in [`core/integer.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/integer.rb#L868-L902),
- in TruffleRuby, it is implemented in [`src/main/java/org/truffleruby/core/numeric/IntegerNodes.java`](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/blob/master/src/main/java/org/truffleruby/core/numeric/IntegerNodes.java#L792-L862),
- in MRuby, it is implemented in [`src/numeric.c`](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/src/numeric.c#L1686-L1707) which delegates to [`cmpnum`](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/74597c6159a8d5fd40347f9a5643e12ffe54581f/src/numeric.c#L1641-L1684),
- in Opal, it technically does not exist (this is one of the few instances where Opal is not compliant with the Ruby Language Specification) because Opal does not have Ruby `Float`s or `Integer`s, it only has ECMAScript `number`s; for those, `Number#<=>` is implemented in [`opal/corelib/number.rb`](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/number.rb#L183-L210),
- in JRuby, `Integer` is an abstract class, so it only has a declaration of `Integer#<=>` in [`core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyInteger.java`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyInteger.java#L918-L920), the actual implementations are in the two subclasses `Fixnum` ([`core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyFixnum.java#L1043-L1060`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyFixnum.java#L1043-L1060)) and `Bignum` ([`core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyBignum.java`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyBignum.java#L992-L1012)),
- in IronRuby, it is implemented in [`Src/Libraries/Extensions/ClrInteger.cs`](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironruby/blob/master/Src/Libraries/Extensions/ClrInteger.cs#L728-L740) (at least for `Integer`s that fit into a C# `int`) and just delegates to [C#'s `int.CompareTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.compareto), and
- in YARV, it is implemented in [`numeric.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/numeric.c#L4671-L4709) and delegates to either [`fix_cmp`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/numeric.c#L4647-L4669) or `big_cmp` (defined in [`bignum.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/bignum.c#L5417-L5443)).

However, I personally find it not so much interesting where something is *implemented* but rather where it is *specified*. `Integer#<=>` is specified in section 15.2.8.3.6 *`Integer#<=>`* of the ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification. A less formal specification is given in [`core/integer/comparison_spec.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/integer/comparison_spec.rb) of The Ruby Spec Suite aka `ruby/spec`.

It is also described in *The Ruby Programming Language* by David Flanagan and Yukihiro 'matz' Matsumoto, *Programming Ruby* by Dave Thomas, Andy Hunt, and Chad Fowler, and of course in the [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E).

Comment: I didn't know Ruby had variants/flavors. This is an awesome list

Answer (score 0):

`<=>` isn't implemented within the `Comparable` module:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Comparable.html

This operation is implemented within each Ruby type (for example - [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), [Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)). For default Ruby types it is possible to compare  only objects of the same type, if you will try to compare it with something different you will get the nil value.

In your example LineA is a method for objects of Geeksforgeeks class, so you can use it as `gfg_object <=> other_gfg_object`. By the way your implementation of `<=>` isn't quite correct, it should checks that `other_name` is an instance of `Geekforgeeks` class (or another type) and return `nil` if it isn't. Correct example:

```
    def <=>(object)
        if object.is_a? Geekforgeeks
            return name.length <=> object.name.length
        elsif object.is_a? String
            return name.length <=>object.length
        else 
            return nil
        end
    end
```

Comment: No `elif` in Ruby.